# Powershell how to exclude folders from deletion process

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that is used to delete all types of files from a Windows machine which are older than x days from a Root Folder and its SubFolders. This was working fine, however now I want to exclude 2 subfolders from the deletion process. Tried **Exclude** command but since I am not familiar with Powershell I am struggling to get it correct.

```
PowerShell version: 5.1
```

Folder structure (Want to exclude SubDir 2 and SubDir3 from deletion process)

```
MainDir
     |
  SubDir1 -> Folder1 -> Folder2 -> Zip/CSV files 
  SubDir2 -> Folder1 ->.txt files
               |
              Folder2 -> .txt files
  SubDir3 -> Zip files
  SubDir4 -> Folder1 -> zip/csv files
```

Script:

```
param([string] $dir = "C:\MainDir", 
      [string] $days = "15")
      $error.clear()
      try
      {


     $refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days)
    Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and  $_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate } | 
    Remove-Item -Force

    }


    catch  {

  Write-Error  $_

  }

  if (!$error) {
Write-Host  'Data deleted for files which are older than' $days 'Days'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using PS 5.1, you can use the `-File` switch instead of having to use `!$_.PSIsContainer` in the Where clause.

To Exclude the subfolders, you can try the code below:

```
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days).Date  # set to midnight
$excludeFolders = 'SubDir2', 'SubDir3'      # an array of folder names to exclude

# create a regex of the folders to exclude
# each folder will be Regex Escaped and joined together with the OR symbol '|'
$notThese = ($excludeFolders | ForEach-Object { [Regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse -File | 
Where-Object { $_.DirectoryName -notmatch $notThese -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate } | 
Remove-Item -Force
```